# Add a contact to android emulator

Tags: android, emulation, addition, contacts

My issue is quite simple I think :

I would like to be able to add a contact to the contact list by a simple click on a button (and be able to test it on the emulator). The data of this contact would be stored in the source code of the application.
is there an easy way of doing that?

thank you for your answers

Comment: You want to have a button that adds a contact to your contact list? And add the data of this contact into your *source code*? I am confused about what you are asking. Can you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only easy way to insert a contact is to use an `INSERT` action, where you supply some of the data and start up an activity for the user to provide the rest and confirm adding it to the contacts list. [Here is a sample project demonstrating this](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Contacts/Inserter/).

Comment: Thanks Mr Murphy, I'll have a look and post here if I have a problem

Comment: If I want to add an icon or a secondary email though, it doesn't seem to work. even if I use Insert.SECONDARY_EMAIL_TYPE
(and i don't know what to use and if it ise possible for the icon)